# Error 8/40 PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I execute this stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure "delete-archive"
is 
begin
for i in (select * from table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR'))
    where FILENAME like 'JDE%')
    loop
    UTL_FILE.FREMOVE ('DATA_PUMP_DIR', i.filename );
    end loop;
end;
```

I get this error:

> 8/40      PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid

The owner has execute permission. It was like that `GRANT DBA TO pqp;`. Do you think that the problem may be permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Answers originally left as comments:

---

[Gerard H. Pille](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/143823/gerard-h-pille): A stored procedure can't use permissions granted via a role. You need:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL TO PQP
```

---

[Albert Godfrind](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/121292/albert-godfrind): As an aside, granting DBA to a regular user or application is a very bad idea. It should only ever be granted to an actual DBA account.

Answer (score 0):

The points about permissions and roles are all valid, but this particular error appears to be a syntax error, not a permissions error. The error message "8/40      PLS-00364: loop index variable 'I' use is invalid" is referring to the call to "UTL_FILE.FREMOVE", not the select statement.

Also not sure the select statement should be implicit (i.e. "select *"). In general these should be explicit to ensure what you're getting back matches the number of variables to be inserted into (i.e. "select FILENAME" matches up with the cursor, "i.filename").

```
create or replace procedure "delete-archive"
is 
begin
    for i in (select filename 
                from table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR'))
               where FILENAME like 'JDE%')
    loop
        UTL_FILE.FREMOVE ('DATA_PUMP_DIR', i.filename );
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: The only real difference from your original is explicitly calling out "filename" in the select statement instead of the implicit "*". See if that helps.